# BottomSheet with RecyclerView and other views

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout, bottom-sheet

I have a CoordinatorLayout with a BottomSheet. Everything works fine if the Bottomsheet has only a RecyclerView. I tried to add some Textview and buttons on top of the RecyclerView, but the recyclerview scrolls beneath the other view when it reaches the top height. I want the other views to scrool too.
If the BottomSheet contains only other views(without Recyclerview) works fine too.
When I combine RecyclerView and other view elements (Button, TextView) the scrolling is not as expected.

I thought to set the views above Recyclerview as the first item of the list but this adds complexity to the adapter.

```
   <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      app:behavior_hideable="false"
      app:behavior_peekHeight="80dp"
      app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

      <Button
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Button 1"/>
      <TextView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Text 2"/>
      <TextView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Text 3"/>

      <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:clipToPadding="true"/>
   </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 6):

Use NestedScrollView as a parent of LinearLayout.
It will solve your problem.

Comment: It's not recommended to use NestedScrollView as a parent of RecyclerView, It will prevent recycling items